# Further Optimisation of Project Euler problem 14 (Collatz Sequence)

Tags: python, collatz

When I first starting trying the question, my code would take over a minute to even finish running and give me the answer. I have already tried dynamic programming and storing previous numbers so it doesn't have to run the same number multiple times. I have also tried compacting (n*3)+1 and n / 2 into a single line with ((n*3)+1) but both of these has only managed to cut my code to 10 seconds. Is there anything else I can try to speed up my code?

```
def Collatz(n):
  dic = {a: 0 for a in range(1,1000000)}
  dic[1] = 0
  dic[2] = 1
  number,length = 1,1
  for i in range(3,n,1):
    z = i
    testlength = 0
    loop = "T"
    while loop == "T":
      if z % 2 == 0:
        z = z / 2
        testlength += 1
      else:
        z = ((z*3)+1) / 2
        testlength += 2
      if z < i:
        testlength += dic[z]
        loop = "F"
    dic[i] = testlength
    if testlength > length:
      print(i,testlength)
      number,length = i,testlength
  return number,length
print(Collatz(1000000))
```

Comment: Why are you using the strings "T" and "F" instead of the booleans True and False?

Comment: Get rid of `loop` and use `break` instead of `loop = "F"`

Comment: Alright I have done that and it seem to have helped speed up the ode a bit, thanks. Is there anything else I can do or should change?

Comment: Take out the print statement. It slows things down massively

Comment: I have tried taking out the printing every time the largest number updates, but it doesn't seem to speed things up too much(maybe around 1 second faster) and I don't get updates so I'm not too such if the code is running sometimes. Is there anything else or is that everything I can do to speed up the code?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it's slower than yours. I was recording a list of all the steps I made, and adding them into the dictionary, but that's overkill

Comment: Oh. So there isnt anything else I can do to make the code run faster?

Comment: @HelloEveryone : I've improved the speed a bit, making use of some of MattTimmermans' ideas but sticking to a recursive solution. I prefer my solution a bit, in so much as `collatz(n)` returns the length of the sequence for given `n` and the logic of finding the maximum is not inside the function. Also it cuts the time by about 10%.

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate the sequence for one input, you find out the sequence length for *all* the intermediate values.  It helps to remember all of these in the dictionary so you never have to calculate a sequence twice of any number < n.

I also started at (n-1)//2, since there's no point testing any number x if 2x is going to be tested later, because 2x will certainly have a longer sequence:

```
def Collatz(n):
    dic = [-1]*n
    dic[1] = 0
    bestlen = 0
    bestval = 1
    q=[]
    for i in range((n-1)//2,n,1):
        q.clear()
        z = i
        while z >= n or dic[z] < 0:
            q.append(z)
            if z % 2 == 0:
                z = z//2
            else:
                z = z*3+1
        testlen = len(q)+dic[z]
        if testlen > bestlen:
            bestlen = testlen
            bestval = i
            print (bestval, bestlen)
        for j in range(0,len(q)):
            z = q[j]
            if z < n:
                dic[z] = testlen-j
    return bestval, bestlen

print(Collatz(1000000))
```

Comment: Did you run `%timeit` on this?

Comment: Interesting. Very similar to my delete approach, but 22% faster than OP's code, while mine was 35% slower.

Comment: Oh I didnt think about that before. Thanks! Also, would it be faster to test x, check if its (n-1)//2, then if it is then have the key 2x have the value +1. So instead of not running x because its going to be run under 2x, you dont run 2x because its just x with a +1 value.

Comment: I don't think that will help

Comment: @MattTimmermans : Your dictionary is actually an array.

Comment: @vorrade, yes.  An array is a lot faster, and if you have dense integer keys, it takes less space, too.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer from Matt Timmermanns is fast, it is not quite as easy to understand as a recursive function. Here is my attempt that is actually faster for `n = 10*million` and perhaps easier to understand...

```
f = 10000000

def collatz(n):
    if n>=collatz.bounds:
        if (n % 4) == 0:
            return collatz(n//4)+2
        if (n % 2) == 0:
            return collatz(n//2)+1
        return collatz((3*n+1)//2)+2
    if collatz.memory[n]>=0:
        return collatz.memory[n]
    if (n % 2) == 0:
        count = collatz(n//2)+1
    else:
        count = collatz((3*n+1)//2)+2
    collatz.memory[n] = count
    return count

collatz.memory = [-1]*f
collatz.memory[1] = 0
collatz.bounds = f

highest = max(collatz(i) for i in range(f//2, f+1))
highest_n = collatz.memory.index(highest)

print(f"collatz({highest_n}) is {highest}")
```

My results:

```
$ time /usr/bin/python3 collatz.py 
collatz(8400511) is 685

real    0m9.445s
user    0m9.375s
sys     0m0.060s
```

Compared to

```
$ time /usr/bin/python3 mattsCollatz.py 
(8400511, 685)

real    0m10.672s
user    0m10.599s
sys     0m0.066s
```